# Hard coded Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app which is connected to `Firebase`.
I have set the rules in the database so that one user (lets name it testUsr) has the permission to read the database but not write to it.
In the `iOS` app I implemented the login function to the firebase, BUT I hard coded the username and password for the testUsr.
So my question is that **will my app get rejected for that hard coded user authentication if I publish it someday?**

Comment: YouWhat error are you getting in the console? And could you share your code?

Comment: I don’t think you understand my question but it’s probably my fault. I don’t have any errors, everything works fine as it should. I was just wondering if it would be a problem at the point of app reviewing that I used the authentication information in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your application will be rejected by Apple because you are using a login service without implementing login with Apple (According to the most recently issued guidelines). They might make an exception though if the whole process happens in code alone—I'm not sure but I would avoid the hassle.

Why is a login required at all? Can't you just make your database on the firebase side read-only without the need of a sign-in at all? You can alter the rules in your database I'm thinking something like. Let me know if it doesn't work and ill do some more researching.

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == "**YOUR MAC ACCOUNT**";
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I don't want to make the database read only because there is a separate macOS app which writes to the database but it is only for my own usage, I'm not going to publish it in the App Store.

Comment: Wait is it possible to make the rules that there is no need to authenticate if I just want to read the database but you need to authenticate if you want to write to the db? Maybe this  does not make any sense but I am just thinking

Comment: I updated my answer. I think this might work.  Also, here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language

Comment: Okay so I changed the rules to: "allow read;" and removed the login function from the IOS app. Does this mean that my app will not be rejected because of this problem?

Comment: I think it should be fine now just as long as your auth work is only being done on your side and not on the client side. Just curious what sort of app is this?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Michael Wells. It is a News Reader app for my school.